# How to delete original file during grunt-contrib-copy file renaming operation?

Tags: regex, node.js, gruntjs, rename

I mostly have what I need from grunt-contrib-copy, in that I am renaming filenames, and the contents within files, using 'rename' and 'options.process'. The final step I'm missing, is how to remove the original file that got renamed in the process.

Here's what I've got:

```
copy: {
  rename: {
    files: [
      {
        expand: true,
        filter: 'isFile',
        cwd: './', 
        src: ['**','!**/*.json','!**/.git/**','!**/node_modules/**','!**/*.sql','!README.md'],
        dest: './',
        rename: function(dest, src) {

          var replaceValue = package.themeReplaceName;
          var start = src.search(replaceValue);
          var end = start + replaceValue.length;

          if (start === -1) {
            return src;
          }

          var returnVal = dest + src.substring(0, start) + package.projectTitle + src.substring(end);

          grunt.log.writeln(returnVal);

          return returnVal;
        }

      }
    ],

    options: {
      process: function (content, srcpath) {

        var newContent = content.split(package.themeReplaceName).join(package.projectTitle);
        grunt.log.writeln('Processing ' + srcpath + 'for ' + package.themeReplaceName + 'replacement...');

        return newContent;
      },
    }

  }
}
```

This results in all of my files renamed, and their contents replaced, but any files that were renamed have their original files still in place.

How might I remove them succinctly?

Also, if you want awesome points, you could have a go at replacing my 'rename' method with an appropriate regex in 'src' if you like!

Thanks in advance,
d

Comment: why not use grunt-contrib-clean to do this job?

Comment: I shall look into it, thanks

Comment: @Louis Barranqueiro OK, where to from here? I don't see how I can integrate grunt-contrib-clean into what I'm doing succinctly? I'm not changing file extensions, so I can just run a "delete all .php" files like I see in the examples I've seen so far. I think I need to delete the originally copied file, just after it's copied to somehow make sure I don't have to re-write a bunch of regex or rules to avoid deleting the wrong stuff, if I need to recurse through all of my files again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use grunt-contrib-clean to remove the file.

module.exports = function(grunt) {

```
grunt.config.set('clean', {

    options: { force: true },
    clean: {
        src: ["path/yourfile","path/yourfile2"]
        }});
```